# Why the Eden size grow while the Minor GC time reduce？

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In a blog I find the a sentence say:when the size of Eden grow, the time of Minor GC will reduce.
But in my opinion, when Eden grow larger, the number of objects linked to the GC root also grow, then the copy behavior will be more frequent which lead to longer Minor GC time. So can anyone explain that, thx~

Comment: Goal of minor GC is to clear fresh garbage in Eden space. So more work!

Answer (score 0):

The time between two minor GCs is determined by the time it takes to fill Eden space with new objects - so its something like (eden-size)/(object-creation-rate). So the larger Eden is, the more time elapses between two GC runs and the more objects have time to die young.

On the other hand the time used by the copy-collector is independent of the amount of garbage to be collected but depends only on the number of live objects to be copied. Having more objects die while still in Eden-space means there's less objects to copy over to the Survivor space and thus less time spent on minor GCs.

Comment: thanks for ur great answer, which help me to have a better understanding!